# How can I change the color GLFW window titlebar

Tags: c++, glfw

I am using GLFW library to create a window. Currently, the window's title is in white color even though I am using dark mode in Windows. Is there a way to change this color manually or make it so it is based on OS theme?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GLFW doesn’t have any function for this. Check this [codes](https://github.com/ysc3839/win32-darkmode/blob/cc26549b65b25d6f3168a80238792545bd401271/win32-darkmode/DarkMode.h#L107-L123) for change window to darkmode.

Comment: You can also use code from the Windows Terminal repository: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/v0.8.10261.0/src/interactivity/win32/windowtheme.cpp